# ListFragment onListItemClick strange behaviour

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

In my CustomList fragment I want to show an image inside item layout each time item is clicked:

```
public class CustomList extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
  ...

  @Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);

    ImageView imageToShow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.myImageId);
    if (imageToShow != null) {
      if (imageToShow.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
        imageToShow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

The row item layout has an ImageView with visibility attribute set to "invisible"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tooth="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/pl.vmcard"
  <!-- ... -->
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_event"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is, when row item is clicked, the image appears for it, but also it appears for other item from the bottom of the list. So if I click item on position 0, the image appears also on item with position 7. I can't figure out what is the reason for that behaviour.

**Edit - CustomAdapter.getView() method:**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
  ...
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    if (position % 2 == 0)
      row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background_even);
    else
      row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background_odd);
    return row;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Post your `getView` code of the `CustomAdapter`

Comment: @Apoorv: Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `ListView` pools views. You do not get a number of views equal to the `adapter.getSize()` but you get the number of views that fit the screen. This is made for performance reasons. What you should do is to change your `dataset` accordingly to the action you perform in `onListItemClick` , and let the `getView` managing the view's visibility

Comment: Yes, I was thinking to put this into CustomAdapter class, but I will face some difficulties when hiding the image after another item is clicked (show at current and hide in previous).

Comment: What kind of issue? The custom adapter is the correct way to go

Comment: for example, when I `setOnClickListener` in Adapter class, the `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` I set in CustomList doesn't seem to work.

Comment: but why you need `setOnClickListener` in the adapter?

Comment: How else can I grab a state of list item (pressed, activated) in Adapter class?